# Laravel Passport how to login without a password, only using a mobile phone?

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I get the following error when logging in with my mobile phone:

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 422

how can i fix this?

My Controller

```
public function login(Request $request)
    {

        $req = Request::create(route('passport.token'), 'POST', [
            //'grant_type' => 'password',
            'client_id' => 2,
            'client_secret' => '326g3KM3giN4o3UHITByxPLHaZlWzqfZbWs0vWLd',
            'phone_number' => $request->phone_number,
            //'password' => $request->password,
        ]);

        $response = app()->handle($req);

        if ($response->status() == 400) {

            return response()->json([
                'message' => ''
            ]);
        } else if ($response->status() == 401) {

            return response()->json([
                'message' => ''
            ]);
        }

        return $response;
```

I also redefined functions in the user model

```
 public function findForPassport($identifier) {
        return $this->where('phone_number', $identifier)->first();
    }

    public function validateForPassportPasswordGrant($password)
    {
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: why did you hide `//'password' => $request->password,`  and `//'grant_type' => 'password',`?

Comment: I returned them and I get the same

Comment: What should I do if my database does not have a password?

Comment: As I see, you don't have validation. Please ensure phone and password are not empty

Comment: You said there is no password in DB, please describe the structure, which you wanna implement

Comment: I want to sign in using a mobile phone, which will receive a code to enter

Answer (score 0):

I've read your description. So, you have to store phone and code in the table users. To simplify it, you can store code in DB field password as an encrypted value.

```
$user->phone_number = $request->phone_number;
$user->password = bcrypt($code);
```

And then during login you can use your own code:

```
    $req = Request::create(route('passport.token'), 'POST', [
        'grant_type' => 'password',
        'client_id' => 2,
        'client_secret' => '326g3KM3giN4o3UHITByxPLHaZlWzqfZbWs0vWLd',
        'phone_number' => $request->phone_number,
        'password' => $request->code,
    ]);

    $response = app()->handle($req);
```